# MIPS function syscall printing random number/memory address instead of parameter

Tags: assembly, mips, low-level, mips32, mips64

I'm new to MIPS and I'm trying to write a very basic function that takes 4 numbers (so 4 parameters) and adds them together. I'm doing it so 3 of the numbers are **hard-coded** in memory and the 4th number (x) is received by user input.

Right now I'm just trying to print all 4 numbers once I'm inside the function (just to verify that they were all passed in correctly), but instead it's printing a random long number (the address?) and I can't tell what's going on.

```
.data

# initialize variables
num1:
    .word 10
num2:
    .word 15
num3: 
    .word -7
    
    
x:
    .word 0


input_msg: 
    .asciiz "Enter a number for x :"


.text
        
.globl main

main:

    addiu $sp, $sp, -4  

    #get value of x from user input
    la $a0, input_msg
    jal getInteger
    move $s0, $v0  #returned value goes into $s0 (this all works correctly)

    #parameters for function call
    move $a0, $s0
    la $a1, num1
    la $a2, num2
    la $a3, num3
    jal add_nums

    addiu $sp, $sp, 4

    # end of program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

add_nums:
    #allocate stack space
    addiu $sp, $sp, -16

    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    li $v0, 1
    syscall
```

It prints "111111268500992" which I assume is arbitrary, but what's really going on here? I thought I understood function calls but this has me perplexed.

Comment: Incomplete code, so cannot reproduce.

Comment: Sorry I didn't add the getInteger input function, but I know that that is working correctly, so for all intents and purposes a number is simply stored in $s0

Comment: I withdrew my answer post since the question has been edited to address that piece.

Comment: You tagged this [mips64].  What 64-bit MIPS simulator are you using?  Those look like MARS/SPIM system calls; I'm not sure they support 64-bit register widths / addresses.  MARS 4.5 doesn't assemble `dadd $t0, $t1, $t2`, a double-word add.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah sorry about that! I didn't realize there was a distinction, I am using MARS but I'm on a 64 bit OS so I thought that meant 64bit. My mistake!

Comment: MIPS64 would apply if the emulated MIPS machine was 64-bit, and you were using its 64-bit features.  (Or more exactly, if you were using a MIPS with MIPS64r1 through r6 extensions; MIPS64 doesn't mean the same thing as MIPS III, the first revision of MIPS that introduced 64-bit register width. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32/MIPS64).  The whole point of a simulator like MARS is that the host doesn't matter; it's written in Java.